# Failed to register error while running pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The pyspark command was working fine until python upgraded from python2.7 to python 3.8. So I changed path variables in bashrc file. I also installed the anaconda navigator made a 3.6 env as it is considered most stable with Spark. Then I ran "pysprak" command which gave me:

[image: error pic].

Update:
I reinstalled pyspark and changed to python 2.7 env, updated bashrc file but still the same error.
[error even using python2.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXttF.png)
Any help appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

[image: Bashrc path variables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was a python error instead of a pyspark error. Finally, solved it. This hack needs to be used coz of major updates with syntax in python 3.8. I opened init.py file put whole content before "%" in rounded brackets "()" [ i.e. (module "%s" (%s) failed to register') % \ ] and it opened PySpark shell

[line 124](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNjKw.png)